# Practice AP and WebCAPE Exams and study guides

Tags: teaching, chinese, exams

I'm creating a language teaching curriculum which will follow ACTFL and World Readiness Standard guidelines.

My end goal is for students to pass the US domestic AP exam (with a 4 or better) and/or a 350-450 on the WebCAPE. For both the AP exam and WebCAPE, these scores are equal to about 4th semester in college.

To do this, firstly I'm designing the curriculum within the ACTFL framework. This provides a good high level overview of how I can teach and measure students performance within the 5Cs of language education. But now I need concrete "things" to teach. For example, what will it take to pass an AP or WebCAPE exam?

For this, I need to see what these actual tests look like. What words are learned? What is the exact curriculum? [This resource](https://secure-media.collegeboard.org/digitalServices/pdf/ap/ap-chinese-course-description.pdf) gives a good high level overview of the course, but not the grammar patterns and vocabulary required.

So, I want to start with AP. Are there AP sample tests available from tests students have taken in prior years? What are some good workbooks and practice sets that prep for the exam? I'll take these and work backwards from there.